# Polynomial regression in python

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python, linear

How do I implement polynomial regression in Python? Do I just use the LinearRegression or is there some special library that I can use?

I understand that is a very broad question, but I could not find any clear implementations from a simple google search.

If anyone has implemented polynomial regression in python before, help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Not a really stats.stackexchange question but, anyhow, you can basically use linear regression and transform your independent variables (this way you preserve linearity in the parameters).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check Polynomial regression implemented using sklearn [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html).

If you know Linear Regression, Polynomial Regression is almost the same except that you choose the degree of the polynomial, convert it into a suitable form to be used by the linear regressor later.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X_train = [[1,2],[2,4],[6,7]]
y_train = [1.2, 4.5, 6.7]
X_test = [[1,3],[2,5]]    

# create a Linear Regressor   
lin_regressor = LinearRegression()

# pass the order of your polynomial here  
poly = PolynomialFeatures(2)

# convert to be used further to linear regression
X_transform = poly.fit_transform(X_train)

# fit this to Linear Regressor
lin_regressor.fit(X_transform,y_train) 

# get the predictions
X_test_transform = poly.fit_transform(X_test)
y_preds = lin_regressor.predict(X_test_transform)
```

Comment: ValueError: shapes (2,2) and (6,) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 6 (dim 0)

Comment: I am not sure if this is correct, but imho `X_test` also has to be transformed to get `y_preds`. So it will be: `X_test_transf = poly.fit_transform(X_test)` and then `y_preds = lin_regressor.predict(X_test_transf )`. If anyone can clarify this, I'd be really thankful.